# difference between jstl-api and jstl-impl

Tags: java, jar, jstl

I'm a beginner in Java EE technologies. I wonder what the difference is between the `jstl-api` jar and the `jstl-impl` jar.

Why are the API and implementation separated? Does it mean there are other implementations available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The API and implementation are separated, because Java EE works with a standardized specification.

The API is part of that specification, and contains a set of mostly interfaces to which everybody that participated in creating said specification agreed. In theory everyone can make an implementation that implements the published standardized API and behaves as described in the associated specification document. You are allowed to call your implementation "certified" when it passes the so-called TCK (Technical Compliance Kit).

It's a stated goal of this specification system to encourage competition, while at the same protected users form being locked-in to any specific implementation.

JSTL in particular is part of the JSP spec, which has been developed under [JSR 245](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=245). If you would like to make your own implementation, you'd begin with reading the [spec document](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/index.html).

> Could you point me to any tutorials that explain how to write our own impl for jstl?

There are as far as I know no specific tutorials for creating your own implementation of whatever Java EE specification. It's in nearly all cases pretty much an expert job, and a job which is typically only carried out by a select few organizations or individuals. This kind of material doesn't really lend itself to tutorial-like write ups, although David Blevins (of TomEE fame) has given us the occasional glimpse in the work that is approximately involved with this.

Comment: My glassfish server has `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.jar`, but it does not have `jstl-impl.jar`. Will this be a problem if I want to use JSTL in my JSP files ? My tutorial uses GF3 and has both jars, while my environment has GF4 and servlet-jstl jar.

Answer (score 3):

jstl-api contains the interfaces that need to be implemented. The jstl-impl contains the standard or default implementation of those implementations. Why do you need both? because if you want the standard or default functionality you use the jstl-impl, but if you want to implement your own behaviour, you can override the methods of the interfaces in jstl-api. That's what a API means: Application Programming Interface. Best regards.

Comment: could you point me to any tutorials that explain how to write our own impl for jstl?

Comment: http://www.noppanit.com/how-to-create-a-custom-function-for-jstl/
I hope it could help you. That's for functions, but there are for custom tags:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31614/JSP-JSTL-Custom-Tag-Library
Best regards