# What constitutes a Java API

Tags: java, c++

my question is sort of related to this post: [difference between jstl-api and jstl-impl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176846/difference-between-jstl-api-and-jstl-impl)

However, in my case I am dealing with the software provided to us by some project partners. Said partners have provided me with their "code" which consists essentially of two jar files: `Software.api-version1.jar`,
and `Software.impl-version2.jar`. Both archives contain `class` files. The implementation is apparently obfuscated so I can't really see what is going on, but the API contains a lot of documented classes. However, these seem to be interfaces / abstract classes.

My question is the following:

What exactly is considered to be a Java API? Coming from C/C++ to me the term API means a set of classes with method declarations. The implementation then consists of the implementation of these methods. Since in C++ code is usually split up between headers (*.h, containing the definitions) and sources (*.cpp, containing the implementation) it is possible to have different implementations for the headers. I have never seen different implementations for the same functionality but I guess it could be done.

In contrast I am rather unsure about how a Java API works. What am I to do with abstract classes which I can't instantiate? I would have to get an instance of an implementing class somewhere but returning such an instance would already *be* part of the implementation wouldn't it?

Comment: As you say these are *documented* classes, the documentation should tell you how to obtain an implementation (or whether you are supposed to create an implementation/ subclass).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about a Java API that distinguishes from a C++ API or any other API. In other words, if you're having a conversation with a Java developer and you say "Java API" they're not going to think of anything much different than if you said "C++ API" or "REST API".

What you're seeing is a convention for packaging class files. When a library provider splits their implementation into an "API" and "implementation" JAR, they've usually done so because you will compile your project against the API JAR while the environment (e.g. a server) will provide the implementation. Conventionally the implementation JAR should contain everything the "API JAR" contains *plus* the implementations, so the implementation JAR actually provides the API too!

Most third-party libraries are delivered in one JAR. I'm not sure why your project partners are splitting it into two. The reason some Java EE libraries do this is keep the deployment lean: you don't need the implementations because the container (e.g. Glassfish, TomcatEE) will provide them.

In theory you can use their API JAR to compile against. You won't be able to run your application or tests unless you mock their implementations. Also in theory you could just ignore the API JAR and use the implementation JAR instead, unless the API JAR actually contains classes the implementation JAR doesn't, in which case your project partners are really doing their own thing.

Regardless, you should definitely just ask your project partners why they packaged files this way, as there is nothing essential to Java that requires it.

#### See also

- [difference between jstl-api and jstl-impl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176846/difference-between-jstl-api-and-jstl-impl)
- [JavaMail API from Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22020533/javamail-api-from-maven)

Comment: So essentially `javac source.java` will work, but `java binary.jar` will not because the definitions are not found? I guess the reason for splitting up the package was to obfuscate as much code as possible...

Comment: @hfhc2, that would be one reason to split up the package, yes. If your implementations are "proprietary" you could give your partners your API without giving them your implementation. I think some PaaS or SaaS providers operate this way: they will provide you with an API JAR to compile your project with, but it won't be runnable except for on their platform. The funny thing is that in this case your project partners have provided both their API and implementation, so they haven't really achieved any additional obfuscation: you could always repackage the JARs into a single one yourself.

Comment: @hfhc2, my best guess is that your client partners have a convention for packaging libraries and they're following it to the letter, even if it doesn't serve any useful purpose here.

Answer (score 0):

***Java SPI*** Not necessarily the case, but a standard java mechanism to decouple interfaces (API) from implementations.

It might be that they use the [**Java Service Provider Interface**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html) or [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html) by which one can detect an implementing class of some interface `com.sioux.MyInterf`.
Look in the implementation jar (`Software.impl-version2.jar`). If you find in the jar a text file `META-INF/services/com.sioux.MyInterf` then in that file one (or more) implementing classes are listed. Probably for a top-level **factory** class.

To use the first implementation of an interface (API):

```
MyIntf api = ServiceLoader.load(MyIntf.class).next();
```

Comment: Well, nothing there, but I just spotted a `Bundle-Activator` line in the implementation manifest. Might this be the way to package OSGi bundles?!

Comment: Yes, and OSGi - as you know - provides its own  service management.